# view extension in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can you please tell why page in not getting inherited

File Structure:
Views> backEnd>masterPage.blade.php

```
<body>
<header class="main-header">
</header>

@yield('content')

<footer class="main-footer">
</footer>
```

File Structure:
Views> backEnd>usercontrol>home.blade.php

```
@extends('backEnd.masterPage')
@section('content')

 <div class="content-wrapper">
</div>

  @stop
```

at current i am not using Controller,just using routes.php

```
Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('backEnd.masterPage');
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, replace `@endsection` with `@stop`. The endsection tag depreciated in Laravel 4.

Then in your routes.php

`Route::get('home', function () { return view('backEnd.usercontrol.home'); })`

Comment: Still Not working, i just wanted to make it bold thats why it showed **@yield('content')** and yes Header has closing tag too. its still not working.

Comment: do i need to add something in controller? 
as of now i am just using routes.php 
Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('backEnd.masterPage');
});

Comment: That's it then, you don't return your masterPage view, you'd return your home view. I've edited my answer to include the route.

Comment: Someone Down voted an answer that helped someone solve a problem?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to access through controller there are some debugging tips that might help you

> 1 clear you cache by this `php artisan cache:clear`
>
> 2 dump-auto load your file by `composer dump-autoload --optimize`

as such there is no mistake found in your code it should work after optimizing

> noted:

please change your route to child view

```
Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('backEnd.usercontrol.home');
});
```

Comment: always welcome dear if above solved your problem please accept the answer